# RxJava, Request's execution time has to be > 1sec but < 5sec

Tags: android, rx-java

How to build a beautiful sequence in Rx for that requirements:

- Request's execution time has to be > 1sec (request could finished earlier but result should be received by subscriber after 1sec, like it has executed more than 1 sec) and < 5sec (otherwise emit timeout error)?

I think about that sequence, but i'm not sure if it is optimal
(**raw scheme**):

```
   Observable<Long> timeoutError = Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .concatWith(Observable.error(new Exception("TIMEOUT!")));
   Observable<RequestResult> request = Observable.combineLatest(Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
        Observable.from(request), new Func2<Long, RequestResult, RequestResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public RequestResult call(Long aLong, RequestResult result) {
                        return result;
                    }
                });
   Observable.merge(timeoutError, request) (maybe .take(1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with the simple operators [`delay`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html) and [`timeout`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html)?

```
test.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

`test` is the observable who's result you want.

Here is an example:

```
CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);

// create tests
Observable<Observable<String>> tests = Observable.just(0, 3, 6)
        .map(i -> Observable.just("request done after " + i + " seocnds").delay(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
// test
tests.flatMap(test -> test.zipWith(
    // delay minimum 1 sec
    Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (r, d) -> r)
    // timeout entire observable in a mixmum of 5 sec
    .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .doOnTerminate(() -> cdl.countDown()).subscribe(i -> {
            // valid
            System.out.println("Item emitted: #" + i);
        } , err -> {
            // error
            System.err.println("Error on item: #:" + err.getMessage());
            err.printStackTrace();
        } , () -> {
            // done
            System.out.println("Done");
        });
cdl.await();
```

Comment: .timeout is ok, thanks! But with delay we add extra 1 second to the source observable (test/request). If request is executed longer than 1 sec we don't need extra delay.

Comment: @ADK changed to `zip`, is this what you need?

Comment: I've  ended up with Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just(request), Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECOND).take(1)).timeout(5, timeUnit.SECOND);